# React App wont run using npm run dev, by use of concurrently

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-ci

I am working on a React app that I just pulled down from Github. I ran an npm ci once pulled down and opened the project hoping it would run. I'm getting an error when I am trying to run the client and server using npm run dev by use of concurrently.

What I'm not understanding is other developers have opened the project and have no problem getting the project to run. Is there a problem with my computer's configuration or is this an npm issue?

Error Message:

```
[1] > PFP-Skeleton@1.0.0 client /Users/sam/Desktop/SchoolFolder/Capstone/march17/PrestonFoodBank
[1] > npm start --prefix client
[1] 
[0] 
[0] > PFP-Skeleton@1.0.0 server /Users/sam/Desktop/SchoolFolder/Capstone/march17/PrestonFoodBank
[0] > nodemon server.js
[0] 
[0] [nodemon] 2.0.15
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js app.js`
[1] 
[1] > multipage-site@0.1.0 start /Users/sam/Desktop/SchoolFolder/Capstone/march17/PrestonFoodBank/client
[1] > react-scripts start
[1] 
[1] sh: react-scripts: command not found
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! syscall spawn
[1] npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
[1] npm ERR! multipage-site@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
[1] npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
[1] npm ERR! 
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the multipage-site@0.1.0 start script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1] npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
[1] 
[1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[1] npm ERR!     /Users/sam/.npm/_logs/2022-03-17T20_08_54_290Z-debug.log
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! errno 1
[1] npm ERR! PFP-Skeleton@1.0.0 client: `npm start --prefix client`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR! 
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the PFP-Skeleton@1.0.0 client script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1] 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[1] npm ERR!     /Users/sam/.npm/_logs/2022-03-17T20_08_54_325Z-debug.log
[1] npm run client exited with code 1
[0] server up on http://localhost:5001
[0] Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
[0] Database synced
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "PFP-Skeleton",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.16.1",
    "tedious": "^14.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: The error mentions you're missing node_modules folder, which means you need to run ```npm install``` before calling ```npm run dev```

Comment: @GianlucaFuoco that's the strange thing about this. I have a node_modules folder in the root where I am running npm run dev

Comment: I see. You can try deleting node_modules folder, and package.lock.json file. Then try reinstalling and running

Comment: @GianlucaFuoco I've have tried this as well with no success

Comment: @GianlucaFuoco Are you aware if there is anything the could possibly be causing the issue within my computeres configuration? Other dev's have pulled the project and have been able to run npm start wtihout any issues

Comment: Sorry I cant tell right off the bat. I'd suggest taking a look at the log file here /Users/sam/.npm/_logs/2022-03-17T20_08_54_325Z-debug.log and seeing if it has any information